# Modulus PHP Problem

Tags: php, modulo

I have a problem, I am trying to calculate what the lowest prime is of a number but I do not understand the result that PHP is giving me.

If I have this number

```
 $number = 600851475143;
```

Then I modulus it:

```
$primes = array( 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97);

    foreach($primes as $key=>$value) {    
        if($number % $value == 0 ) {echo $value; break; }
    }
```

Why is it that $value = 3? If $value = 3, that means that 600851475143 / 3 **should** be an integer, but its not. So I do not understand why that if() evaluates to true?

Comment: When I ran that it didn't print 3 ?

Comment: Take a look at this : http://codepad.org/cjCD14gJ

Comment: And this : http://codepad.org/R9l8wBuv

Comment: `600851475143 % 3 == 2` for me, but I'm using PHP 5.2.5 on 64 bit linux.  I'm willing to bet you're on 32 bit, so your max integer is smaller.  For me, `php -r 'var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX);'` returns
`int(9223372036854775807)` -- try this in your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP 5.2.8, it fails as described in the question. It seems like the modulo operator doesn't work on big integers. You should consider using `bc_mod` (modulus with arbitrary precision):

```
<?php

$number = 600851475143;

$primes = array(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97);

    foreach($primes as $key=>$value)
    {    
        if($number % $value == 0 ) {echo $value."<br/>"; }
        if(bcmod($number, $value) == 0) {echo "bcmod ".$value."<br/>"; }
    }

?>
```

The above code prints:

> 3
>
> 29
>
> bcmod 71

Answer (score 4):

See this [bug listing here](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=25328)

% does not not work for numbers over 2^31 (32-bit) or 2^63 (64-bit). Use [BCMOD](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcmod.php) instead.

Comment: Yeah. I just found that. Its because it is a float.

Comment: Works fine for me using PHP 5.2.5 on a 64 bit platform (I'd expect modulus to work for numbers up to 2^63, on such a system).  But I'm sure modulus on 32 bit platforms still has that limitation, which shouldn't come as any surprise.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding it, but modulo gives you the rest of a division, so e.g. 600851475143 / 3 is 200283825047 rest 2 and this is what it gives you back.

Comment: Yes. I know. So $number % 3 should equal?