# modulus remainder different from java and php

Tags: java, php

I'm trying to implement two methods in PHP and JAVA that return a common integer and have the same output.

internal parameters match but when it comes to modular division, it fails.

My numbers are stored as int.

In PHP i have this result

> 1192581159 % 100000000 = 85278720

In Java i have this result

> 1192581159 % 100000000 = 92581159

**LATER_EDIT_WHILE_POSTING_QUESTION** i think 1192581159 is bigger that PHP_MAX_INT , a possible solution is to treat it as a string and apply substrings in order to get correct result from Java

Comment: yes, the question might be why or asking for a second opinion

Comment: My version of PHP 5.3.1 gives 92581159

Comment: When I run the reverse `intval(92581159 * 100000000)` I get 360859392 go figure

Comment: i'm running PHP 5.4.7, java result should match php result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is described here

[Modulus PHP Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366117/modulus-php-problem)

my approach was to treat 1192581159 as a string and substring the result needed for my calculations

```
    $bigint = (string)$bigint;
    $bigint = substr($bigint,-$returnDigits);
    // $returnDigits is the same as the last
    // x numbers from the end of my "string"
```