# If a number is multiple of 3 starting at different numbers

Tags: php, math

I'm not sure of the mathematical term for what I'm after, but I'm looking for a way in PHP to assign a variable to an integer which is a multiple of three. The multiple will start from numbers 1, 2 and 3. All integers will fall under one of three variables `$varA`, `$varB` and `$varC`. I think the modulus operator should be used, but I'm not sure how.

`$varA` could include numbers 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19 etc.
`$varB` could include numbers 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20 etc.
`$varC` could include numbers 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21 etc.

I want to assign the number from an if statement, such as:

```
if( $number == (test for $varA) ) {
    $number = $varA
} else if( $number == (test for $varB) ) {
    $number = $varB
} else {
    $number = $varC
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you need the modulo (not modulus) operator. This gives the remainder when divided by three - either 0, 1 or 2.

The first test would be:

```
if ($number % 3 == 1)
```

You may wish to evaluate only once and use in a switch statement - as the other David comments below, this is marginally more efficient:

```
switch ($number % 3) {
    case 1:
        $number = $varA;
        break;
    case 2:
        $number = $varB;
        break;
    case 0:
        $number = $varC;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a switch, based on the result of `$number%3` be more efficient (if only to avoid multiple assessments of the condition)?

Comment: Yes, it would marginally. Not directly an answer to the question, but worth suggesting. I'll edit in.

Comment: I advise using bcmod($number, 3). Note that the % operator can fail if any oerand is above 100,000 or so - a known bug.

Comment: Yes, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366117/modulus-php-problem

Comment: Thanks, just what I was after